# how to add space between string and integer using python

Tags: python, string

How do I add space between a string and an integer, and also if i want to print in new line?
This is my code, so output will be, 1000normal, but
my output should be like this

```
1000 normal
```

or

```
1000
normal
```

How do I achieve this?
Below is code attempt.

```
w = 40
h = 5
b = (w * (pow(h, 2)))
f1 = "normal"
f2 = "average"
if b >= 500:
    print(str(b)+f1)
else:
    print(str(b)+f2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For space:

```
print(str(b), f1)
```

For printing with a newline between b and f1:

```
print(str(b) + '\n' + f1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The most basic way would be to use string concatenation:

```
print(str(b) + ' ' + f1)
```

But note the default `sep` parameter for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a single whitespace. So you can just use:

```
print(str(b), f1)            # single space separator
print(str(b), f1, sep='\n')  # new line separator
```

With Python 3.6+ you can use formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
print(f'{b} {f1}')           # single space separator
print(f'{b}\n{f1}')          # new line separator
```